# Django Constraints - Case Insensitivity

Tags: django, django-models

I have defined a unique constraint below. I am wondering if there is a way to make the firstname and lastname fields case insensitive without having to write raw SQL? I have looked in the documentation and can't find anything on how to do this.

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields= ['firstname','lastname','dateofbirth'],name="unique_person"),
    ]
```

Comment: If you are using Postgres you can use a Case Insensitive CharField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#citext-fields, or you could create a slug field for the first and last name, and validate against them

Comment: I am using Postgres so will give that a try.

Comment: What about the ones without Postgress?